# RavenDB: How to use Multi Maps / Reduce indexes

Tags: .net, nosql, mapreduce, ravendb

I have quite simple model:

```
public class PhraseMeta:
{
 public int Id { get; set; }
 public string ModuleName { get; set; }
 public string Description { get; set; }
 public DateTime ModifiedDate { get; set; }
}

public class Phrase
{
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public int PhraseMetaId { get; set; } //reference to PhraseMeta
  public string Language { get; set; }
  public string Text { get; set; }
}
```

Phrase contains some translations and PhraseMeta has meta information for several Phrases.
I am trying to find Phrase's Text having ModuleName and Language. 
As I understood RavenDB's Multi Maps / Reduce indexes feature can help with it instead of using WhereEntityIs.
My index is:

```
public class PhraseEntry
{
  public string MetaId { get; set; }
  public string ModuleName { get; set; }
  public string Language { get; set; }
  public string Text { get; set; } 
}

public class PhraseTranslationIndex : AbstractMultiMapIndexCreationTask<PhraseEntry>
{
  public PhraseTranslationIndex()
  {
    this.AddMap<PhraseMeta>(phraseMetas => from pm in phraseMetas
                 select new
                 {
                   MetaId = pm.Id,
                   ModuleName = pm.ModuleName,
                   Language = (string)null,
                   Text = (string)null
                 });

    this.AddMap<Phrase>(phrases => from phrase in phrases
               select new
               {
                 MetaId = phrase.PhraseMetaId,
                 ModuleName = (string)null,
                 Language = phrase.Language,
                 Text = phrase.Text
               });

    this.Reduce = results => from entry in results
                 group entry by entry.MetaId
                   into g
                   select new
                   {
                     MetaId = g.Key,
                     ModuleName = g.Select(x => x.ModuleName).Where(x => x != null).First(),
                     Language = g.Select(x => x.Language).Where(x => x != null).First(),
                     Text = g.Select(x => x.Text).Where(x => x != null).First()
                   };

    this.Index(x => x.ModuleName, FieldIndexing.Analyzed);
    this.Index(x => x.Language, FieldIndexing.Analyzed);
    this.Index(x => x.Text, FieldIndexing.Analyzed);
  }
}
```

This is how I am trying to use it:

```
var entry = documentSession.Query<PhraseEntry, PhraseTranslationIndex>
                           .Where(p => p.ModuleName == "MyModule")
                           .Where(p => p.Language == "en")
                           .FirstOrDefault();
```

And this index has no results. I am using build 472.

Any ideas?

Comment: May be it's better to ask in mailing list http://groups.google.com/group/ravendb/

Comment: 1. What management studio says?
2. Can you see this index, does it has errors or something in management studio?
3. What is the result of the same index but without reduce?
4. May be First() fails? Try g.Select(x => x.Text).FirstOrDefault(x => x != null)

Comment: 1. Management studio says: "sequence contains no elements";

Comment: 2. Yes, I can see this index, but it show only first map and reduce functions. There is no second map function.

Comment: 3. Map functions seems to be working: I can see "raw" data of PhraseEntry (Count is number of PhraseMetas + number of Phrases).

Comment: It seems like Reduce function: "group entry by entry.MetaId" does not work properly. That is quite strange because Map functions result has MetaId in all entries.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is probably that you are using First(), try using FirstOrDefault()